# TF Object Detection API: Inference in very high resolution images

Tags: tensorflow

I have trained a model (faster rcnn based) to identify 80x80 sized objects in 1000x600 images.

Inference works well when presented with 1000x600 test image.

However, my final goal is to be able to detect such objects (80x80) in very high res photographs (5000x4000 or higher, sometimes 10x of that).

What options do I have?

One way I am thinking is to split the large image into smaller images of 1000x600 and do inference on them. But there are challenges in that approach.

Anyone has tried this use case and found any workable solution?

--

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is:

1. Reduce the size of the image 5000x4000 -> 1000x600
2. Predict the objects; you will get the `xminx, xmaxs, ymins, ymaxs` -> normalize them by width and height to get a value space of 0 and 1
3. Take the original image and re-normalized the object boxes by the original width and height

Your suggested approach to split the image should work as well but will be computationally more expensive.

Comment: I tried this. Compressing the image would make the objects of interest loose their features (my objects are very small, actually.  I am using aerial photos) leading to lots of false negatives.  My first try with the splitting->detecting->stitching approach worked well, but handling corner cases is pending.

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

- do patch-by-patch inference and use non-maximum-suppression to handle border cases, or
- make your training images the same size as your testing images by padding.

Let us know what you ended up doing!